# Error slf4j and file does not exist while reading a file from HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to read a file (csv file) from HDFS using a Java program. I have searched multiple sources resolve the below issue but still could not.  Please help.

( Note : The requirement is as above so I am using java and not python or scala or spark or any other)

I tried something like below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


public class hadoop2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

        Path file = new Path("/usr1/myFile0.csv");

            try (FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf)) {

                FSDataInputStream is = hdfs.open(file);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

                String lineRead = br.readLine();
                while (lineRead != null) {
                    System.out.println(lineRead);
                    lineRead = br.readLine();
                    //do what ever needed
                }

                br.close();
                hdfs.close();
            }
        }
}
```

It outputs error :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sigmoid/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-reload4j/1.7.36/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sigmoid/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /usr1/myFile0.csv does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:976)
    at hadoop2.main(hadoop2.java:22)
```

I do not understand what exactly is going wrong here. And how to tackle it. I have tried using importing from maven SLF4J but its of no use.

Also the program outputs File /usr1/myFile0.csv does not exist But the file is present. as you can see from the screenshot.

[image]

Update:

I was able to eliminate the error slf4j. How I did it was to go to file structure of the project and under maven dependency there were two bindings listed, I deleted both by mistake then I added latest one again.

The error now shows.

```
Aug 17, 2022 1:40:35 AM org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader <clinit>
WARNING: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs:/usr1/myFile0.csv, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:807)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:976)
    at hadoop2.main(hadoop2.java:22)
```

Comment: Can you suggest whats wrong and what would be a correct path so that I can try and confirm.

Comment: Maybe your config does not specify defaultFS. Can you try to change the path you're trying to read as `Path file = new Path("hdfs:///usr1/myFile0.csv");` ?

Comment: Wrong FS: hdfs:/usr1/myFile0.csv, expected: file:///
This is what I get as error message now when I changed as you had suggested.

Comment: How about if you change 1) conf setup as `conf.addResource(new Path(Paths.get("/etc/hadoop/conf/xxxx-site.xml").toUri()));` , and 2) move `Path file = new Path("hdfs:///usr1/myFile0.csv");` inside try block, i.e. after file system is initialized?

Comment: It still doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve it:

1. SLF4J error.
   *Resolution:* As stated in question's update.
   I was able to eliminate the error slf4j. How I did it was to go to file
   structure of the project and under maven dependency there were two
   bindings listed, delete one of it.
2. Error while Read.
   *Resolution:*  Remove the configuration and add below instead:

   From :

   ```
   conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
   conf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
   ```

   To

   ```
   conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
   ```